# Colspan in css table

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm writing a CSS table (via display: table;) and I need row with 3 columns and the next row to have 100% width and so on. Result should seem like this:

```
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
|           |
+-----------+
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
|           |
+-----------+
```

I'm trying to do that with colspan but I haven't found how to do that.
Is it even possible ?

Comment: I rode the topic HTML colspan in CSS, but it didn't help me. I can't use caption.

Comment: Tables are structural elements and just because using colspan changes its appearance does not mean it's not. CSS is used to style elements and not change the structure. So this would not work.